# Check existence of filenames

Tags: bash, if-statement, filenames

I have a simple if-statement that checks if a file exists in a directory. If it matches it returns OK, otherwise, it echos FAIL.

```
if [[  -f Foobarfile_"${TODAY}"*.txt ]]; then echo "OK"; else echo "Fail!"; fi
```

`$TODAY` is a date stamp having YYYY-MM-DD format.

If I have in the directory Foobarfile_2016-01-15_100.txt" as the only file, the if-statement will return true.

I am puzzled because if the directory has multiple files, the if-statement will return false. E.g. if it has another file called "Foobarfile_2016-01-15_101.txt"

It should basically check that as long as the directory has a filename that has today's date stamp, i.e.:

```
Foobarfile_2016-01-15_100.txt
Foobarfile_2016-01-15_101.txt
somethingelse_2016-01-15_102.txt
KrispyKreme_2016-01-14_98.txt
Foobarfile_2016-01-15_104.txt...
```

it should return true. Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to test whether one or more files contain today's date. One way to do that would be to use an array:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( Foobarfile_"${TODAY}"*.txt )
if [[ ${#files} -ge 1 ]]; then
    echo "OK"
fi
```

`shopt -s nullglob` sets the [`nullglob` shell option](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob). With this option set, the array will be empty if no files match the pattern. Otherwise, a failed expansion would result in the array containing one element e.g. `Foobarfile_2016-01-15*.txt`.

Comment: what does shopt - nullglob do?

Comment: Tried your suggestion and seems to work.
But, on another matter, shell seem to have lost autocomplete. e.g

   $ mv Foobarfile <tab for autocomplete> does not work anymore.

I have to unset by executing shopt -u nullglob

Comment: Hmm I can't see why this would affect it; is it broken if you try on a newly opened shell?

Comment: Older bash autocompletion support is known to have issues when options are set to non-default values. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29909046/258523) for a bit about this and a link to a commit that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

if Statement is of type  [[ expression ]]
no pathname expansion shall happen, see the Bash Manual.

In your case, expression [[  will search for file with name 
Foobarfile_2016-01-15*.txt which does not exist.

That's you are getting "Fail" print.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. That is useful to know, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ -f Foobarfile_$(date --rfc-3339=date)*.txt ] && echo "OK" || echo "no joy"
```